# Is it possible to get the text log for Disk Utility First Aid check?

Tags: macos, disk-utility

Does/can the standard Disk Utility in OS X (El Capitan) log the "First Aid" disk check results in text file?

<sup>Copy paste does not work on this control and to record the whole log I had to take 22 screenshots.</sup>

Or maybe there is a CLI counterpart to this check?

[image: Disk Utility First Aid result]

Comment: Have you been able to find a log file? Per [this 2010 answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/172078/630402) there _was_ a log file in ~/Library/Logs/DiskUtility.log but I can find nothing with macOS 10.12.5 (using the Finder's search, spotlight or `sudo find / -name "DiskUtility.log"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI counterpart would be `diskutil repairVolume /Volumes/MyPassport`.